# Unable to override slick scroll with jqueryfullpage scroll

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, slick.js

I'm using JqueryFullpage plugin for my website. Inside which I have a vertical slick scroll. When I'ms scrolling the slick slider using mouse or in mobile, the scroll of slick slider is not getting effected and the jqueryfullpage scroll is getting effected.

Below is my code for fullpage

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
            menu: '#menu',
            scrollingSpeed: 1000, //responsive: 991,
            scrollBar: true,
            navigation: true,
            responsiveHeight: 540,
            touchSensitivity: 10,
            resize: false,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
                $(this).find('.animated').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('in');
                });
                $('.section:not(".active")').find('.animated').each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('in');
                });
            },
            afterRender: function() {},                             
        });
```

Below is my code for slick

```
$(".vertical").slick({
            dots: false,
            vertical: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            nextArrow: '.slick-prev',
            prevArrow: '.slick-next',
             verticalSwiping: true,
            verticalScrolling: true,
        swipe:true,

        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haribol,

Have you tried:

"normalScrollElements: (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'). This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.".... Ys